# How to extend load event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Hi I am opening a page inside iframe, using jQuery **[.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)** so I want to extend this .load method, so that I can execute my own code before jQuery start executing .load event.

```
 $("body").find("iframe").load(function () {
            // my code here
             myMethod();   
  });
```

Now how can I customize .load event of jquery to call `myMethod()` before .load callback.

Comment: it's unclear please add some code....

Comment: If I get this right you just have to put your code outside of `.load()`

Comment: @Spokey no I want to call myMethod() before iframe starts loading page.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an xy problem.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  From your question, calling `myMethod()` before you call `load()` sounds like what you want.  But I get the feeling that you are trying to do something else.

Comment: @Smeegs basically I want to show a loading image whenever a new page is loaded inside iframe, to accomplish this, on document ready I've set iframe to hidden, and when page loaded, then show it again.

Loaded page have window.location to load new page inside iframe, now how I show loading when again new page loads inside iframe.

Answer (score 1):

- Can't the image be loaded before calling load() function. Something like

      `$('a').click(function(){
           //show image
           //call onload
     }`
- JQuery.ajax(...) with beforeSend can also be used to achieve the same. In beforeSend, show the loading image and return true